# separate data from 1 column to 2 column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset consisting of 1 column. In this column there are 2 data. How to separate the data into a second column. i want my dataset to be 2 columns. Thank you

here is my dataset :

[image]

i wanna make like this :

[image]

Comment: Is that a file? If a CSV(comma separated values) or TSV(Tab separated values) then you can use the pandas library to read the file into a structured data strucutre.

Comment: Is each row a string or a list or something else?

Comment: @Vishnudev how? my file is TSV

Comment: @MattMiguel yess..each row is string

Answer (score 1):

If your file is tab delimited, just use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.from_csv(file_path,sep='\t')
```

Comment: @Sarada This is how you read a TSV file in pandas

Comment: I have tried it but i got an error like this :
 
Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 712938

Comment: @Sarada Does every row have the same number of columns? If your first few rows are formatted differently, you might have to skip them with df = pd.from_csv(file_path,sep='\t',skiprows=2). This for example skips the first two rows. Alternatively you can do
 pd.from_csv(file_path,sep='\t',error_bad_lines=False) to make it skip problematic lines instead of throwing errors.

Comment: @MattMiguel I'm still getting the same error :(  But thanks

Comment: @Sarada Does something look wrong if you go to row 712938 in your data file? Does it look like all the other rows? Also I just noticed you said C error. You might need to change the parser engine from C to python. pd.read_csv(file_path,sep='\t',error_bad_lines=False, engine="python")

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

Directly read the file using `read_csv` and define these parameters to specify `'\t'` as delimiter and to ignore error lines set `error_bad_lines=False`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('SINGGALANG.tsv',sep='\t',header=None,names=["Tokens","Tags"],error_bad_lines=False, engine="python")
```

Alternatively, If you want to read all the data in 1 column and then to split it in different columns you can do following:

Assuming, you have dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['val1 0','val2  0','val3  0'])
```

You can use split and create columns.

```
df[["col1","col2"]] = df[0].str.split(expand=True)
```

Comment: what should i fill in ['val1 0','val2  0','val3  0']}) ? My dataset doesn't have any column headers

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly, as you specified there is no header.

Comment: sorry sir, would you mind to see my dataset https://github.com/ialfina/ner-dataset-modified-dee/tree/master/singgalang. My dataset is singgalang.tsv. In the dataset there is a token followed by its label. But the token and label are in 1 column
whereas I want to make tokens and labels in different  columns.. Thanks

Comment: You can directly read your tsv file using read_csv function, and define following parameters to make it work, that will be more optimal. If you want to convert an already created column into 2 then you can use the 2nd method.